# Timeline of record multiple satellite launches

Tags: artificial-satellite, reference-request, payload-deployment

The Transporter 1 mission has placed 143 satellites into low orbit in one go. The previous record was held by the Indian ISRO PSLV C37 mission with 104 satellites in 2017.

Where can I find a complete list of all the multiple launches that set a record in their time?

Comment: Kiksat - 105 sattelites in 2015  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KickSat